# How to prevent YouTube video name from showing up when changing volume in Windows 10. [YouTube IFrame Api]

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

**Question**: how to prevent YouTube video name from showing up when changing volume in Windows 10. [YouTube IFrame Api]

**What I don't want:**

[Image of what I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkmCH.png)

I don't want the name of the YT video to show up when changing volume. It's really annoying and I can't find any way to disable it.

Is there some kind of playervar that stops this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you currently cannot change Chrome flags to disable this from code. The best you can do is provide a direct link to the setting, as the flags page supports direct links to specific settings: chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling

In the meantime, we'll just have to wait and make feature requests to Google. Maybe they can add a popup that says, "This website is trying to change a setting...", or something.

Answer (score 1):

It is a browser feature, If you are using chrome you can disable this feature by navigating to `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` and then disable **Hardware Media Key Handling**

[image]

Comment: Any way to do this code wise so a normal person using the website wouldn't see this? I don't want my site users to experience this. But thanks for the response!

Comment: I'll upvote the answer when I figure out how to do that. I'm searching Stackoverflow but am finding nothing about it :/

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome browser answer is already present. Adding it for Firefox browser.

1. Launch firefox browser.
2. Open settings.
3. Scroll down till you see options like below snapshot.
   [image]

4. Uncheck highlighted option in above step.
5. Bingo, if still not working relaunch the firefox application again.